# Rails 4: Add Column To An Existing Scaffold

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Yes, this question is flooded on here but most are few years back and I am using Rails 4. I have tried few and it messed up my rails app so I wont take anymore chances.

I have already created a scaffold with fields and I have made many changes to its model, controller and views. Imagine you are working for someone when few weeks later, after you've created a scaffold, they realized they missed out an important column - lol

```
rails g scaffold Book a:string b:integer
```

How do I easily add `c:date`?

Few examples showed running a migration and few says edit the rails console. I am confused with the `rails g migration add_this_to_that c:data`??

Any reference with your answer is highly appreciated as I'm still learning RoR.

Comment: What is that: >edit the rails console? Creating a new migration is the way to go.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov A website said to edit rails console. Could you post an answer regarding "creating new migration"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add new column, you should create migration:

```
rails g migration add_c_to_books c:date
```

(note the syntax: add_x_to_y), which will add this file to **db/migrate/*timestamp*_add_c_to_books.rb**:

```
class AddCToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :c, :date
  end
end
```

Now all you need is to run it with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

That's it.

---

You can add multiple columns with:

```
rails g migration add_c_d_e_to_books c:date d:string e:integer
```

Which will create following migration:

```
class AddCDEToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :c, :date
    add_column :books, :d, :string
    add_column :books, :e, :integer
  end
end
```

---

Or name it however you want:

```
rails g migration my_migration
```

Which will result in clean migration:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

You are free to specify your directives inside `def change`.

Comment: So basically I only need to modify the views? If I need to perform calculations on that column (c), does it creates another model or it's the same `book.rb`?

Comment: @Sylar you need to modify all places where you want to use `c`. If you want to add it to form: add it to view, then you probably want to save it - modify controller(add `c` to `def book_params .permit`), if you want to validate it - add corresponding code to book model etc. You don't need to create new m/v/c files, just modify existing ones.

Comment: Thanks! Any way other way of adding more columns in one go? ie: c, d, e?

Comment: @Sylar of course you can. For example, try `rails g migration add_c_d_e_to_books c:date d:string e:integer` and look into file created. Then you can remove it and add migration you need as you'll understand how it works.

Comment: @Sylar by the way it isn't restriction to specify columns in `rails g migration ...` command. You can name it whatever you want, for example `rails g migration my_awesome_migration`, which will create new migration with empty `def change` method, and add any code you want inside. Then run migration to apply your changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70946/discussion-between-sylar-and-rustam-a-gasanov).

Comment: Excellent, really comprehensive answer! Helped a lot